# How this question is off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I mean this question:

[How would Earth's climate differ if it's axis were tilted around 90 degrees like Uranus?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/853/how-would-earths-climate-differ-if-its-axis-were-tilted-around-90-degrees-like?rq=1)

The closing moderator said the question is about Earth science, but in fact the question about Earth's orbital motion in Solar System, which is NOT a part of Earth's science, but a part of astronomy. Also the question is not exactly about Earth but about a hypothetical planet that has similar physical characteristics but different rotation mode.

Answer (score 2):

The author isn't asking about the orbital motion; they're asking about the *climate.* There's nothing about the "seasons, temperature, and life on Earth" that makes it [within the scope of *this* site](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The questions may or may not fit on Earth Science; I'll have to leave that for *them* to discuss.

Comment: Are not calendar and study of seasons parts of astronomy?

Comment: @Anixx No, they aren't.

Comment: Calenders and seasons on planets other than Earth.